# VMware windows 10 does not working with error: Unable to open file "E:\w10\Windows 10.vmdk"

Tags: windows-10, virtual-machine, vmware, vmdk

I recently rebooted my computer and when I tried to reopen my virtual Windows 10, I found out that it is not working and the following error appearing:

Unable to open file "E:\w10\Windows 10.vmdk"
The system cannot find the file specified.

These are all the files in Windows 10 folder:
[image]

Also, No information is available about the hard disk of this virtual windows as shown below:

[image]

this is another pic for the files with more details:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KVzZl.png)

and these are the errors
[errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QJejn.png)
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i3RQ8.png)
The properties of the files are as follows:
[properties 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YxVVO.png)
[properties 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/55T3r.png)
[properties 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/44P0q.png)
[properties 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5O4CJ.png)
Is there any way to fix this issue?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Could you tweak File Explorer to show file extensions? Also, what are the file properties of `Windows 10.vmdk`? Is it perhaps a shortcut or something?

Comment: @barrycarter hi, thanks for your response, I edited my question. Now you can see more details. I didn't change anything and I didn't add any shortcuts.

Comment: When you say `These are all the files in Windows 10 folder`  you mean the `w10` folder, right?

Comment: @barrycarter yes exactly

Comment: For all the files named `Windows 10`, could you "see properties" and give me the actual extensions (not the file types). Obviously, one of them should be `.vmdk`. I did notice a 0-byte `Windows 10` file, but that appears to be snapshots, so it might be ok that file is empty. You can also go to a DOS prompt and do `dir` if it's easier

Comment: @barrycarter I edited the question by adding 4 new Pictures. If you want to check anything else, please tell me to send it. Thank you very much.

Comment: Well, the file appears to exist and is 1397 bytes long. See if you can load it into notepad? It's just a configuration file, so it should be quite readable. If that doesn't work, look at the "Security", "Details", and "Previous Versions" for just the file that says "VMware virtual disk file (.vmdk)".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137787/discussion-between-barrycarter-and-hamed-peyrovedin).

Answer (score 0):

I see the issue. You opened/ran VMWare with or without Admin privs and the file needs those privs to be opened. I can tell from the one **Error** linked pic you have, the `Add` button at the bottom should not have that Admin symbol on it. So it is a permissions issue and you probably just have to `Run As Administrator` right-click option when you run VMWare.

[image: Admin Button]

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick response but unfortunately, it didn't solve the problem and the problem is still here :(

Comment: Is the E:\ Drive a Main. internal drive?

Comment: E:\ is the internal drive but my main Windows is installed on drive C:\.

Comment: I am slightly confused. You mean E:\ is **AN** internal drive, but C:\ is your main? Did you ever move/copy & paste the files?

Comment: since it is a virtual windows, I didn't install it on drive C. I didn't move or copy/paste any file.

Comment: Wait, so what did you do to get your internal drive to identify as both E:\ and C:\? **BTW** it does not matter that it is 'virtual windows' you can install it right on your regular hard drive. It is not going to *take over* your system or anything. When you install it should be on your C:\ (or whatever is your Main Drive) VMWare will create a folder called Virtual Machines for you.